# Check if a BSTR is empty

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++

I have a variant that contains a BSTR, but sometimes the BSTR is "" (empty), so how to avoid this? I have tried something like:

```
variant.bstrVal != NULL
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `SysStringLen`:

```
if (SysStringLen(variant.bstrVal) == 0)
{ ... }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can test the `vt` member of *VARIANT* for `VT_NULL` or `VT_EMPTY`

```
if (variant.vt != VT_NULL)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect; an empty variant is different to a variant set to `VT_BSTR` with empty string

Comment: @M.M apologies for misreading the question. However, a test for `VT_EMPTY` should do the trick.

Comment: VT_EMPTY is also different to VT_BSTR. The question implies that it is known that `variant.vt == VT_BSTR` already.